# Symfony2 (FOSUserBundle) SHA512 hash doesn't match C# SHA512 hash

Tags: c#, asp.net, symfony, asp.net-mvc-4, fosuserbundle

I made an account on my web app (Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle) and registered with the password "lolwut" (without the quotes).

These are the settings in my security.yml config:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
            algorithm:   sha512
            iterations: 1
            encode_as_base64: false
```

The resulting data:

```
Hashed password:
f57470574dbf29026821519b19539d1c2237e4315d881fa412da978af554740c6b284062a9a4af7d0295d18ebea8ef2e152cf674b283f792fe0b568a93f969cf
Salt:
kuc5bixg5u88s4k8ggss4osoksko0g8
```

Now, since the iterations are set on 1, I am assuming that encoding "lolwut" in SHA512 in C# will give me the same result, here's my logic:

```
string salt = "kuc5bixg5u88s4k8ggss4osoksko0g8";
string input = "lolwut";
string passAndSalt = String.Concat(input, salt);

System.String Hashed = System.BitConverter.ToString(((System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512)new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed()).ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passAndSalt))).Replace("-", "");
return passAndSalt + "<br>" + Hashed;
```

However, this returns the following value that doesn't match the FOSUserBundle hashed password at all:

```
82E8CA0408B23DB50EB654EDB50A7926AC73613184054DB82FB6D67CD4186B7A045D265AEDE6E3852CD85B981F15F6615C1C0C6FBF443B1672DF59DE23557BD9
```

I know I must be doing something wrong somewhere, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is, and it's driving me nuts. Could anyone help me out here, please?

Comment: I think C# is base 64 encoding the password, but I might be wrong

Comment: Why are you fully-qualifying all your type names? It makes the code much harder to read - as does putting it all in a single statement...

Comment: @JonSkeet That's because it's not my own code, I copied it from an example to check if it actually works. You're right though, it's unreadable and will be cleaned up once I have this issue sorted. :)

Comment: Do you have any documentation for how Symfony converts the (salt, password) into a byte array to hash?

Comment: You should increase the number of iterations. At least 10000, preferably 100000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony merges password and salt as `password{salt}`, so this code will return the same hash:

```
  string salt = "kuc5bixg5u88s4k8ggss4osoksko0g8";
  string input = "lolwut";
  string passAndSalt = String.Format("{0}{{{1}}}", input, salt);

  System.String Hashed = System.BitConverter.ToString(((System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512)new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed()).ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passAndSalt))).Replace("-", "");
  // Hashed.ToLower()
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that did the trick! C# returned it as an uppercase string, so I did `return Hashed.ToLower()` to match them perfectly.